# connection pooling: retrieve lost DB connection

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, transactions, db2, websphere

I am implementing 2-phase commit for a distributed transaction(using 2 Databases). I simulate a DB server connection loss by pulling the network cable to my desk Computer and then plugging it back. However, this causes the transaction to fail in executing a "rollback" as the DB connection object is lost. Is there a way that i can retrieve the lost DB connection object or enforce the application to try reconnect to the same connection after a certain timeperiod.
I am using DB2 and Websphere 6.1 as the app server. DB connection is thru a jndi lookup. Using Atomikos as the Transaction Manager.

In general, how does an application implementing 2-phase commit recover(rollback) in the scenario of a DB crash? Is the recovery the application's responsibility or should the Transaction Manager do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that your problem has anything to do with recovery because it likely occurs before the 2 phase transaction is prepared.

If you simulate a failure by unplugging the network cable, then the app server will quickly notice that the connection is broken, namely when the application attempts to execute another database operation. However, on the DB2 side, the connection simply looks idle, and it may take a long time for DB2 or the host system where DB2 runs to notice that the connection is broken. The rollback will only occur once the connection has been identified as broken. In the meantime you may have issues because of the locks held by the connection.

If you want to reduce the time it takes before DB2 initiates rollback on the connection, then you may want to tune the TCP keep-alive setting on the server.

Comment: Thanks Andreas..i will test this.
But is there any other way the test can be done without changing the DB server settings? I am mostly sure that this value wnt be modified for production servers. how do i ensure recovery then?

Comment: Strictly speaking "recovery" means resolving in-doubt transactions, i.e. distributed transactions where at least one participant has been requested to prepare the transaction and where not all participants have committed/rolled back. If the failure occurs before the DB2 transaction has been prepared (which is likely the case in your scenario), then no recovery is necessary (for that resource), but the locks will remain until DB2 detects that the connection is broken. If the transaction has been prepared, then recovery should succeed no matter which connection is used.

Comment: thanks for explaining it well..i undrstnd wats goin on now. I guess d lock on d DB is due to DB2 server settings and not due to Application...Let me see wat i can do to change tht. I also have a doubt regarding the transaction not committing as its set to rollbackOnly but i will post a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any idea of Atomikos.

In general, the Transaction Manager is responsible for the recovery. Usually the application server in this case WAS acts as the transaction manager and is responsible for performing this activity.

Once the DB connection is lost, a StaleConnectionException would be received and the WAS runtime would purge this connection or all the DB connection in the connection pool for that database (depending on what you have configured).

A new connection is available to the application upon the next request from ds.getConnection.

The application does not need to perform any recovery activity (as far as the database is concerned).

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Ok..so can you shed some light on recovery for DB2? My application does not perform conenction retrieving activity. However, aftr the DB connection loss, the DB2 database is deadlocked (-911 error), i.e rollback isnt completed successfully.

Comment: I don't see a reason for DB2 deadlocks here. That is surprising

Comment: The update is executed on 1st DB but is not committed. I think thts the reason for deadlock, although, having a 2-phase commit protocol should ideally avoid/recover frm tht.